# Negative air ionizer with a electric net of 3X 230V AC

Tags: ac, ionization

I want to make the following negative air ionizer but the following instrucable uses a net of  230V AC + N.
My question is : If I make the following circuit but power it with the two phases of a 3x230V AC (thus 230V AC)

[image: 1]
<sub>(source: [instructables.com](https://cdn.instructables.com/FOT/WIM1/GCPZMDEY/FOTWIM1GCPZMDEY.LARGE.jpg))</sub>

http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-a-Negative-Ion-air-ionizer/

1. Will it still produce negative ionized air?
2. If not can I modify the circuit and how to do so with my current net?

Comment: Where are the capacitors, its not very clear on this image where the caps are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 230v between the input pins will be OK, but the phase connection going to the 'Neutral grid' will not be, **for safety**, if anyone can touch the grid.

You could fix the safety aspect by making the unit completely enclosed, so there is an insulating grid preventing contact with the neutral grid.

In practice, it may be safe enough to put another two 10M resistors in series with the neutral grid to limit current for personal use, but that doesn't meet the letter of safety regulations so cannot be sold, and really you would not want to allow anyone other than you to touch if you did so.

Comment: alright something i didnt consider but will it still function as a NEGATIVE ionizer?

Comment: That depends on which way round you have the diodes. Keep the negative end to the pointy bits, and you'll get -ve ions.

Comment: i dont understand if you can explain this in the answer i will tick it as THE answer. thank you

Comment: \you've labelled the pins yourself in your diagram, 'negative pins'. That's because they're connected to the negative output of the multiplier. If you turn the diodes round, so their positive ends connect to th epins, then you'll have positive pins, and positive ions. It's nothing to do with whether the neutral plate is connected to 0v AC or to 200v AC, it's whether the pins are +10kv or -10kV with respect to the neutral plate.